# Poner JFileChooser en español

Tags: java, archivo, diálogo, idioma

Tengo un programa en *Java*, que intenta guardar un archivo de texto, y para eso uso `JFileChooser`, pero el problema es que tiene el idioma en inglés.

Pude cambiar solo el título y el botón **Guardar**, pero todavía falta cambiar **Cancel**.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private static String diálogo(String entrada, boolean[][] matriz)
throws IOException {
    JFileChooser ventana = new JFileChooser(entrada);
    ventana.setDialogTitle("Guardar");
    ventana.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Texto (txt)","txt"));
    if (ventana.showDialog(null,"Guardar") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File archivo = ventana.getSelectedFile();
        FileWriter archivo_escribe=new FileWriter(archivo);
        archivo_escribe.write('c');
        archivo_escribe.close();
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es... ¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar el texto de **Cancel**? Si es posible, me gustaría cambiar todos los textos, como **File Name**, o directamente cambiar el idioma del `JFileChooser` al español, porque también veo que dice **Desktop** en vez de **Escritorio**, etc.

Estuve investigando, y al parecer la solución es usar `Locale`, pero en la lista de propiedades no aparece el idioma español, solo aparece esto:

- CANADA, CHINESE, ENGLISH, FRENCH, GERMANY, ITALYAN, JAPANESE, KOREAN, TAIWAN, UK y US

¿Habrá que descargar algo extra?

**La imagen del diálogo:**

[image: Diálogo guardar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá es porque estas usando tu OS en ingles, pero si no es así, `JFileChooser` usa el lenguaje especificado por la propiedad `-Duser.language` con lo cual deberías iniciar la `JVM` con ese parámetro indicando un idioma soportado. Supongamos que mi clase principal se llama `Dialogo`:

***Ejecutar en español con:*** `java -Duser.language=es Dialogo`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
***Italiano***: `java -Duser.language=it Dialogo`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
***Alemán***: `java -Duser.language=de Dialogo`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
***Frances***: `java -Duser.language=fr Dialogo`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]